# Why is my program perceiving an EOF condition way before my file actually ends?

Tags: c, file, pointers, eof, fseek

My code reads line by line from a text file and stores the lines in a massive array of char pointers. When I use an ordinary text file, this works with no issues. However, when I try to read from the 'dictionary.txt' file I'm supposed to be using, my program detects EOF after reading the first of MANY lines in the file.

```
int i = 0;
while( 1 ) {
    
    size_t size = 50;
    fseek( dicFile, 0L, getline( &dictionary[i++], &size, dicFile) ); 
    printf( "%d:\t%s", i, dictionary[i - 1] );
    
    if( feof( dicFile ) ) {  
            fclose( dicFile );
            break;  
    }
    
}
puts("finished loading dictionary");
```

Here is the start of the dictionary file I'm attempting to load:

```
A
A's
AA's
AB's
ABM's
AC's
ACTH's
AI's
AIDS's
AM's
AOL
AOL's
ASCII's
ASL's
ATM's
ATP's
AWOL's
AZ's
```

The output is get from this portion of the program is:

```
1:  A
2:  finished loading dictionary
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `fseek( dicFile, 0L, getline( &dictionary[i++], &size, dicFile) );` What is that supposed to do? The last parameter doesn't look right at all. Why do you need to call `fseek` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third argument to `fseek()` is nuts. I've seen at least one implementation that treated every out of range third argument as SEEK_END. Oops.

You should just call `getline()` in the loop instead. In fact, just check the return value of `getline()` for `-1` and get rid of that `feof()`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I used fseek() that way in a previous project and it worked. I must have read it somewhere disreputable.

Comment: @LinusHasaWalkingDesk We would all very much like to know what you thought the call to fseek would do.

Comment: @zwol: He doesn't know. He tried something random.